# With the php buffer setting turned off, why didn’t a cookie get set?

Tags: php

I have a problem when i take the exam. 
Do any one know why ???

With the php buffer setting turned off, why didn’t a cookie get set?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Question</title>
<?php
$value = 'something from somewhere';
setcookie("QuestionCookie", $value);
?>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cookies are HTTP Headers, and need to be sent before ANY output is sent to the browser.

Comment: What are you using to try to read the cookie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call `setcookie()` before any other output.  By producing HTML before calling `setcookie()`, you eliminate the browser's ability to receive any additional HTTP headers beyond the HTML document headers (a cookie is a header).

```
<?php
// Set cookie before any output
$value = 'something from somewhere';
setcookie("QuestionCookie", $value);
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Question</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify all headers before any content goes out. Cookies use headers to tell the browser which data to store so they need to be before any output as well.

```
<?php
$value = 'something from somewhere';
setcookie("QuestionCookie", $value);
?>
<html>
<head>
...
```